# Google Direction API with 100 or more waypoints

Tags: ios, swift, google-directions-api

I'm developing app for drivers, where he may have more then 100 random pickup points. My application will optimise route for driver. Right now if I'm adding more then 23 waypoints then its returning error for limitation on waypoints . My question is , is there any way to get optimise route with more then 100 waypoints ?
note: I have paid api key, and I'm working on iOS application in swift.

Comment: Try to use polylinencoding. This way you can optimise the route. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm

Comment: appreciating your answer . but my requirement is to arrange random locations in such a way that driver can cover all points in minimum time .

Comment: tried with encoded polyline but it returns same MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED

Comment: You have a business account right?

Comment: yes, i have purchased key.